# Вставка изображения в pdf android

Tags: java, android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Пишу программу по созданию pdf на android, использую java class 
Ниже приведен код uses и создания pdf.

Как загрузить в лист pdf картинку из Image1 (Delphi 10 Seattle).

```
uses 
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, 
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, 
  Androidapi.JNI.Net, 
  Androidapi.Helpers, 
  System.IOUtils;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonCreatePdfClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Document: JPdfDocument;
  PageInfo: JPdfDocument_PageInfo;
  Page: JPdfDocument_Page;
  Canvas: JCanvas;
  Paint: JPaint;
  Rect: JRectF;
  FileName: string;
  OutputStream: JFileOutputStream;
  Intent: JIntent;
  //image:JBitmap;
begin
  // create Pdf document
  Document := TJPdfDocument.JavaClass.init;
  try
    // create page 1
    PageInfo := TJPageInfo_Builder.JavaClass.init(100, 100, 1).create;
    Page := Document.startPage(PageInfo);

    Canvas := Page.getCanvas;
    Paint := TJPaint.JavaClass.init;
    Paint.setARGB($FF, 0, 0, $FF);
    Canvas.drawText(StringToJString('Hello, world!'), 10, 50, Paint);
    Canvas.drawBitmap();
    Document.finishPage(Page);
```

Здесь приведен пример вывода текста.